# Why are the result of COUNT double when I do two join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have this tables

**device**

```
 id      name         groupId     serviceId
791   Mamie Ortega      205         1832
```

**group**

```
 id   serviceId
205     1832
```

**record**

```
 id          date                      deviceId
792   2017-07-13 13:30:19.740360         784
793   2017-07-13 13:30:19.742799         784
```

**alarms**

```
 id    status    deviceId
241      new        784
242      new        784
```

I'm running this query

```
SELECT device.id, device.name, COUNT(records.id) AS "last24HMessagesCount", COUNT(alarms.id) AS "activeAlarmsCount"
FROM device
  INNER JOIN "group" AS "group" ON "device"."groupId" = "group"."id" AND "group"."id" = '205'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "record" AS "records" ON "device"."id" = "records"."deviceId" AND "records"."date" > '2017-07-12 11:43:02.838 +00:00'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "alarm" AS "alarms" ON "device"."id" = "alarms"."deviceId" AND "alarms"."status" = 'new'
WHERE "device"."serviceId" = 1832
GROUP BY device.id;
```

Which give me this result

```
 id      name       last24HMessagesCount      activeAlarmsCount   
791   Mamie Ortega         4                          4
```

This result is wrong, I'm supposed to have 2 for last24HMessagesCount and activeAlarmsCount.

If I remove one of the count, last24HMessagesCount for example and execute

```
SELECT device.id, device.name, COUNT(alarms.id) AS "activeAlarmsCount"
FROM device
  INNER JOIN "group" AS "group" ON "device"."groupId" = "group"."id" AND "group"."id" = '205'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "alarm" AS "alarms" ON "device"."id" = "alarms"."deviceId" AND "alarms"."status" = 'new'
WHERE "device"."serviceId" = 1832
GROUP BY device.id;
```

The result is correct

```
 id      name       activeAlarmsCount   
791   Mamie Ortega         2
```

I do not understand, why are the counts double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple to answer. You have two `record` and two `alarm`. You join these and get four records, which you count.

You can workaround this problem by counting distinct IDs:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT records.id) AS "last24HMessagesCount",
COUNT(DISTINCT alarms.id) AS "activeAlarmsCount"
```

but I would not recommend this. Why do you join `record` and `alarm` anyway? They are not directly related. What you *want* to join is the number of `record` and the number of `alarm`. So aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT 
  device.id, 
  device.name, 
  records.cnt AS "last24HMessagesCount", 
  alarms.cnt AS "activeAlarmsCount"
FROM device
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT deviceId, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM record
  WHERE "date" > '2017-07-12 11:43:02.838 +00:00'
  GROUP BY deviceId
) AS records ON device.id = records.deviceId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT deviceId, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM alarm
  WHERE status = 'new'
  GROUP BY deviceId
) AS alarms ON device.id = alarms.deviceId
WHERE device.serviceId = 1832
  AND device.groupId = 205;
```

(I've removed the unnecessary join to the "group" table.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the query give me this error `column "record.deviceId" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` So it seems that `GROUP BY` is necessary

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clauses. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I managed to find it by myself ;) The problem is that the query was generated by sequelize, a nodejs ORM. But thanks a lot, I will manage to solve this part.

Answer (score 3):

Your joins are producing a Cartesian product along two dimensions.  The simplest solution is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT device.id, device.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT records.id) AS "last24HMessagesCount",
       COUNT(DISTINCT alarms.id) AS "activeAlarmsCount"
```

This works if the counts are not very large.  An alternative solution is more scalable.  That is to do the aggregation *before* the `LEFT JOIN`s or using correlated subqueries (or lateral joins).