# How to aggregate or display only first row after adding column to group by statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate

I need to receive information about volume of products in transit in total and split into three columns depending on the delivery date. In order to do it I had to join to tables that below are called vll and vl.

In order to differentiate the date I build a case statement however once I use vl.arrivdate in the statement I need to add it to Group By as well. Then instead of one line per product I receive three.

Could you please advice how to reach the same result in one line without building another big subquery?

Here is how this part of the query looks like

```
SELECT
SUM(DISTINCT(NVL(vll.qty,0))) as "Transit Total",

CASE
  WHEN vl.arrivdate > camp_demand.start_date + 7 THEN NULL
    ELSE SUM(DISTINCT(NVL(vll.qty,0))) END as "Transit WK1",
    
CASE
  WHEN TO_DATE(vl.arrivdate) BETWEEN camp_demand.start_date + 7 AND camp_demand.start_date + 14 THEN SUM(DISTINCT(NVL(vll.qty,0)))
    ELSE NULL END as "Transit WK2",
      
CASE
  WHEN TO_DATE(vl.arrivdate) > camp_demand.start_date + 14 THEN SUM(DISTINCT(NVL(vll.qty,0)))
    ELSE NULL END as "Transit WK3"
GROUP BY
camp_demand.start_date,
vll.qty,
vl.arrivdate
```

And below is the result as I get it now:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have conditions inside your aggregation functions (`SUM` in your case). This is called conditional aggregation. For one result row per product the query will look something like this:

```
SELECT
  product_no as "Product",
  SUM(vll.qty) as "Transit Total",
  SUM(CASE WHEN vl.arrivdate <  cd.start_date +  7 THEN vll.qty END) as "Transit WK1",
  SUM(CASE WHEN vl.arrivdate >= cd.start_date +  7 
            AND vl.arrivdate <  cd.start_date + 14 THEN vll.qty END) as "Transit WK2",
  SUM(CASE WHEN vl.arrivdate >= cd.start_date + 14 THEN vll.qty END) as "Transit WK3"
FROM ...
GROUP BY product_no
ORDER BY product_no;
```

Your `SUM(DISTINCT ...)` looks dangerous. I suppose that you join too early or on incomplete criteria, thus creating a too big intermediate result with duplicates you then try to get rid of. Maybe you want to show us the whole query and tell us what the tables represent and how they are related.

Comment: Thanks very much, works correctly now.
As for SUM(DISTINCT) can you clarify why it's dangerous and what issues can it cause (is it longer query time)?
I used similar solution elsewhere, as you pointed out I got duplitates there too. I'll show on different column/table for simplicity

Comment: to get sum:  

```SUM(DISTINCT(NVL(inventory.qty,0))) as "Inventory",```  


and join for that column:  

```LEFT JOIN supply.inventory_v@jdasnap_supply inventory ON  
camp_demand.default_variant = inventory.item  
AND camp_demand.loc = inventory.loc  
AND camp_demand.day = inventory.day  
AND inventory.project in ('S','O')```

Comment: As to the danger: You seem to have values, say 100, 100, and 200, and you get them multifold, e.g. thrice: 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, and 200. In order not to get a sum of 1200 (with a mere `sum(value)`), you use `sum(distinct value)` and get 300. But you want 400 (because 100 + 100 + 200 = 400). Maybe this question and answer help you understand such issues and give advice on how to go about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080044/why-are-the-result-of-count-double-when-i-do-two-join